# About Internet Explorer 9 document and browser mode

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

Good day! I have got a question about the Internet Explorer 9. Can anyone tell me if its document and browser mode (I mean rendering as Internet Explorer 8 and 7 when chosen) is appropriate to test HTML and CSS in different versions of the browser?

I used to use something like Multiple IE on my virtual Windows machine, but my colleague use the Internet Explorer 9 to test HTML and CSS "directly". So none of us has a sense of correctness of the chosen solution.

So, that's the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my subjective experience, IE9's 8/7 "Browser Modes" have always been an accurate reflection of the actual browsers - at least for pure HTML/CSS.

However, there are subtle differences when it comes to JavaScript, see the "Differences between IE8 Compatibility View and IE7" section here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/12/site-compatibility-and-ie8.aspx

I usually test with IE9's older "Browser Modes", but if I'm feeling paranoid or I want to be absolutely sure, I use my virtual machines.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the answer to your question is yes - go with the browser modes.

Here is a good article for you
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Few differences that I have seen in IE9 Doc Mode vs real IE8 or IE7:

1) If a PNG image is given opacity (via Proprietary CSS filter), 'Real IE8/IE7' shows black linings.

2) JavaScript performance in 'Real IE8/IE7' is obviously not as fast as IE9.

3) Fonts also tend to have some display issue in various modes: http://blog.typekit.com/2013/03/14/the-dangers-of-cross-browser-testing-with-ie9s-browser-modes/ and font smoothing is an issue in windows XP.

4) Embedded YouTube videos have z-index issues overlapping other elements (fixed by wmode).

5) Proprietary CSS filters work properly in 'Real IE8' but are not shown if applied to an HTML5 element in IE9 doc mode. (Faced this once)

Summary: If the site you are making is JavaScript intense or the client is very much concerned about users on IE7/8, have a check on Real IE 7/8 and get the issues ironed out.